# hidding the eye icon in IE10 inside an IFrame

Tags: c#, css, internet-explorer, authentication, iframe

I have two applications. The first is used as an internal user management application that was developed to for multiple applications to use as a central authentication service. It is placed in an IFrame inside the second application. The second application is the application users are logging into after they have been authenticated. 
My problem is the show password eye icon in IE10. I have the CSS code in the central authentication app to hide the eye icon.

```
.input::-ms-reveal 
{
      display:none;
}
```

When I run just the central authentication app, the eye icon is hidden. However when I run the second app, with the central authentication app inside an IFrame, the CSS appears to be overridden and the eye icon is visible.

Has anyone encounter this before and what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are implementing the IFrame. You need to make sure that page that is located in that IFrame is also pointing to that same CSS.

Comment: The central authentication app, where I currently have the -ms-reveal code, has its css inline. So it should take priority over all other css. correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand 100% completely. But, both the main page and IFrame would require the inline CSS

Comment: There is only one iframe. The iframe is in the main application and it points to the central authentication app. Also I did place the CSS in the sitemaster.css file. The eye icon is still there.

Comment: What is the filename of the content within the IFrame?

Comment: <iframe src="<%: View.Url %>" width="515px" height="280px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>

Comment: I'm not sure if the css is overriden, it seems like it's just not taking it for some reason. Are you sure you're including the sitemaster within the IFrame content?

Comment: I may not be. I thought I was including it correctly. CSS isnt my strong point. How would I include it in the sitemaster within the IFrame content? In my CSS file, I dont see anything specifically for the iframe. I just added .input::-ms-reveal 
{
  display:none;
}
to the bottom of the css file.

Comment: An IFrame is literally another page inside a page. It is completely separate. For example, let's say I have index.htm and mypage.htm. Within index.htm I create an IFrame with the source of mypage.htm. Now, index.htm is using mycss.css as it's css file -- mypage.htm will NOT inherit that css file. You will have to open mypage.htm and also include mycss.css in it's code as well.

Comment: that sounds like what I have already done. the .input::-ms-reveal { display:none; } css code is inside the central authentication app, which is inside the iframe.

Comment: Then I am stumped as well unfortunately. As to your earlier question about the inline css - yes, inline css will take precedence over everything else. Sorry I wasn't able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice, but appending `!important` to the rule might cancel out whatever is causing it to not apply your rule. e.g.

```
.input::-ms-reveal 
{
  display:none !important;
}
```